# java Unit testing

Tags: java, maven, akka

I have an akka maven project and I want to run unit test it.

I have defined the test class but when I run it I have an error displayed.

the actor class code snippet is given below :

```
public class WorkerActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {

         if(msg instanceof GesturePoints) 
         { GesturePoints message = (GesturePoints) msg;
         Result rslt = initial_Theta(message);
         getSender().tell(rslt);
          } 

         else {unhandled(msg);}
    }

    public Result initial_Theta(GesturePoints p) 
    {           
        Result result = new Result();

        if(p.getPoints().get("x").size() < 3)  //The number of x coordinates as size
        {   return null;}                    




 dx = (double) ((Integer)p.getPoints().get("x").get(2)  - (Integer)p.getPoints().get("x").get(0)) ;

  dy = ((Double)p.getPoints().get("y").get(2)) - ((Double)p.getPoints().get("y").get(0));

             {                                          
                   result.setResult("feature1", initial_cos);
                   result.setResult("feature2", initial_sin);

         } 
             return result;
         }  
}
```

the test class is given in the code below

```
public class ActorTest {

    TestKit testKit;
    TestActorRef<WorkerActor>  testedActor ;
    TestProbe tProbe;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {   

        testKit = new TestKit(ActorSystem.apply());
        tProbe =  TestProbe.apply(testKit.system());
        testedActor = TestActorRef.apply(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory()
                {

            public WorkerActor create()
            {
                return new WorkerActor();
            }
                }),testKit.system());
    }

    @Test
    public void testWorkerActor()
    {    
        ArrayList<Object> x = new ArrayList<Object>();
        ArrayList<Object> y = new ArrayList<Object>();
        x.add(0, 1); x.add(1, 2); x.add(2, 3); x.add(3, 4); x.add(4, 5);
        y.add(0, 1.00); y.add(1, 2.00); y.add(2, 3.00); y.add(3, 4.00); y.add(4, 5.00);

        Map<String, ArrayList<Object>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>();
        map.put("x", x);
        map.put("y", y);

        GesturePoints gp = new GesturePoints();
          gp.setPoints(map);

         tProbe = TestProbe.apply(testKit.system());
    testedActor.tell(gp , tProbe.ref());

    TestActor.Message message = tProbe.lastMessage();
    Result result = (Result)message;


assertEquals(0.25 , result.getResult().get("x"));
    assertEquals(0.25 , result.getResult().get("y"));

    }
}
```

the maven also contain a default test class. Both the efault testclass and the `Actortest` class are located in the `src/test/java` folder.

this is the pom file

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.theta.gesture</groupId>
    <artifactId>com-theta-gesture</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>com-theta-gesture</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>Com.RubineEngine.GesturePoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0-SANPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.result.gesture</groupId>
            <artifactId>com-result-gesture</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-remote</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-testkit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>            
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>typesafe</id>
            <name>Typesafe Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repo</id>
            <name>repo</name>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>    
</project>
```

the error message is given below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building com-theta-gesture 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ com-theta-gesture ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ com-theta-gesture ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ com-theta-gesture ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-theta-gesture\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com-theta-gesture ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ com-theta-gesture ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.0.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-theta-gesture\target\surefire-reports
[INFO] Using configured provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Concurrency config is parallel='none', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Running com.theta.gesture.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 sec
Running com.theta.gesture.ActorTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.562 sec <<< FAILURE!
testWorkerActor(com.theta.gesture.ActorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ClassCastException: akka.testkit.TestActor$NullMessage$ cannot be cast to com.result.gesture.Result
    at com.theta.gesture.ActorTest.testWorkerActor(ActorTest.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  testWorkerActor(com.theta.gesture.ActorTest): akka.testkit.TestActor$NullMessage$ cannot be cast to com.result.gesture.Result

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.098s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 23 05:24:12 BST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project com-theta-gesture: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-theta-gesture\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Do I have to add any configuration to the application.conf file

hope somebody will help me out.

Comment: **java.lang.ClassCastException** It means you are type casting to a class which is not in relation with the class.. Check once where you are typecasting wrongly.. It is not configuration issue...:)

Comment: I have added the pom file as you suggested @Mr.Chowdary

Comment: Did you miss something in `WorkerActor` when you copied-and-pasted? e.g. What is `initial_cos` and `initial_sin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ActorTest`, try replacing

```
TestActor.Message message = tProbe.lastMessage();
Result result = (Result)message;
```

With this:

```
tProbe.expectMsgClass(Result.class);     
//TestActor.Message message = tProbe.lastMessage();
//Result result = (Result) message.msg();           <- Important
```

Then change `WorkerActor` to this:

```
if(msg instanceof GesturePoints) { 
    GesturePoints message = (GesturePoints) msg;
    //Result rslt = initial_Theta(message);
    //getSender().tell(rslt);
    getSender().tell(new Result());
}
```

That should pass. This verifies that `WorkerActor` is sending back the right type of message (e.g. a `Result`).

The next step is to uncomment your call to `initial_Theta()` and figure out why that is not populating the `Result` correctly.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, have been able to run without the class cast error but  i get a null result and the test give a failure. Looks like the problem is with how to inject the test data into the actor class. And its like the Actor is not runned do have any suggestion in this regard.

Comment: @faisalabdulai Simplify things first. Change `WorkerActor` to this: `getSender().tell(new Result());` and comment out your `assertEquals` in `ActorTest`. Your test should then pass. Then add another test where you verify the contents of `Result`.